# Best approach for merging solr indexes of size 60GB and 10GB in minimum time?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, indexing

Lets say, I have a Solr Index of 60GB. I want to merge with it a 10GB Solr Index.
What is the best way to merge them in minimum time. Can somebody give me a 
performance benchmark for how fast the merging process can be? I'm using JAVA to merge the index directories.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Lucene's [IndexMergeTool](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool.html) to merge these indexes. This class uses [IndexWriter#addIndexes](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addIndexes%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader...%29) under the hood in case you need to embed this functionality in another tool. If you don't need your index to be optimized in the end, you could even use [IndexWriter#addIndexesNoOptimize](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addIndexesNoOptimize%28org.apache.lucene.store.Directory...%29) which may be faster.

Comment: Hi jpountz, lets say I issue one of the following commands to merge the two index directories,
IndexMergeTool index1(60GB) index2(10GB) destIndex and,
IndexMergeTool index2(10GB) index1(60GB) destIndex

Which one of above is ideal to merge smallest index into the biggest one? Or,
How will IndexMergeTool decide smallest index to merge with the biggest one?

Comment: Lucene MergePolicy will compute the best order to merge segments, so you don't need to do anything. Just run `IndexMergeTool dest index1 index2`. (If you are interested in how it works, see http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.html, the default implementation is TieredMergePolicy since Lucene 3.2 and LogByteSizeMergePolicy for older versions).

Comment: Hi Jpountz, if you don't mind, can you please give me a prediction of how much time it might take to merge a 60 GB file with a 10GB one?

Comment: I can't because there are two many parameters involved: disk i/o, number of terms, number of documents, ...